ESLint 9 is not working properly with Next 15
I've recently migrated my project to Next.js 15, but ESLint isn’t functioning as expected. So far, I've installed the following packages:
"eslint": "9.13.0",
"eslint-config-next": "15.0.1",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.2.1",
"next": "15.0.1"

.prettierrc.json:
{
    "printWidth": 110,
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "endOfLine": "auto",
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true
}

settings.json in VS Code:
{
  "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "typescript",
    "typescriptreact"
  ],  
  
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": "explicit",
    "source.fixAll": "explicit"
  },  
  "prettier.printWidth": 80,
}

eslint.config.mjs:
import pluginNext from '@next/eslint-plugin-next';

export default defineConfig([
    {
        plugins: {
            '@next/next': pluginNext,
        },
    },
    {
        files: ['**/*.ts', '**/*.tsx'],
        rules: {
            ...pluginNext.configs.recommended.rules,
        },
    },
]);


If I add eslintrc.json will work if I run yarn lint but won´t work in real time in VS Code.
Despite the installation, ESLint doesn’t seem to lint my files or show any errors in VS Code. I’d appreciate any guidance on configuring ESLint for Next.js 15. Are there any specific settings or dependencies required for ESLint to work seamlessly with Next.js 15?

"If I add eslintrc.json" What do you mean? Make sure your VSCode is configured with eslint.useFlatConfig set to true

Sorry, just added that, what else should I do? can you elaborate more please? @Arkellys

You talk about a eslintrc.json file but you shared a eslint.config.mjs

Use compatibility mode
Original:
{
  "extends": [
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    "plugin:@tanstack/eslint-plugin-query/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@tanstack/query"]
}

Flat:
import { FlatCompat } from "@eslint/eslintrc"
import path from "path"
import { fileURLToPath } from "url"

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename)

const compat = new FlatCompat({
  baseDirectory: __dirname,
})

/** @type {import('eslint').Linter.Config[]} */
const configs = [
  ...compat.extends("next/core-web-vitals"),
  ...compat.extends("next/typescript"),
  ...compat.extends("plugin:@tanstack/eslint-plugin-query/recommended"),
  ...compat.extends("prettier"),
  ...compat.plugins("@tanstack/query"),
]

export default configs

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/71763#issuecomment-2436288395

Everything works fine for me. Try to restart the eslint server (ctrl+shift+p -> restart eslint server), reload VSCode (ctrl+shift+p -> reload window) and making sure you are using the latest version of the ESLint extension (maybe try switch to pre-release version and repeat the previous steps).

still not working when I use the new structure of eslint 9 :(

I also have this configuration rules in settings.json:
"[typescript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint" },
"[typescriptreact]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint" },
